# Xpath ID created dynamically in each bootstrapping, hence won't be targeted easily

Tags: javascript, css, dom, xpath

Say I desire to change an element with no direct identifiers, but with a similar Xpath:

```
#js_n6 > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a > span > span
```

I would gladly use it Inside a `document.querySelector('')` but there is problem:

The `#js_n6` ID is created dynamically in each bootstrapping (in each time the webpage is formed or refreshed):

In each bootstrapping you get a different Id like `#js-x1`, `#js_v9`, `#js z4`, `#js k1` and so forth, while the rest of the Xpath stays the same.

I tried using a CSS wildcard like `[id^="js"]` for the ID, but it seems to be ineffective because it targets other, earlier elements with the similar ID's found by the wildcard.

---

A direct code example is Facebook.com's conversations page. Go to the page with all conversations and run in console:

```
document.querySelector('.5blh.4-0h').click();
```

Then, inspect the "Delete" button on the modal menu, and view Xpath. Then, refresh and view again and you'll see what I mean to.

I just give this as an example; I ask no one to do any scraping and I don't ask this specifically about Facebook, but rather to get a general principle.

---

I wonder what can be done in that case, to select such an object with no direct identifiers, and with an Xpath with a dynamic ID.

Notes:

1. In any such case I don't own the site and can't add identifiers from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Combining selection of a parent element with a CSS ID wildcard helped.

Here's basically what I did:

1) I selected an element that parents the element with the ID (.idElementParent).
2) I selected the element with dynamic ID with a CSS ID wildcard.
3) I than used the relevant portion of the Xpath.

```
document.querySelector('.idElementParent > [id^="js"] > div > ul > li:nth-child(4)').someMethod();
```